# How to include ASCII art/diagrams in Rust source-code comment documentation?

Tags: rustdoc

How should Markdown be used with rustdoc to include diagrams or ASCII art?

From reading the manual, triple back-ticks can be used for code-snippets.
How do I include literal, non-formatted text?

*(Something like [Doxygen's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) `<pre>...</pre>`)*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You use triple graves

````
```text
like this
```
````

Note the `text`. This tells `rustdoc` to not syntax highlight what's inside; the default is to think it's Rust code.