# How to put a line into the documentation which is ignored for doc tests?

Tags: documentation, rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

How can I write a line into the documenation code but let the compiler ignore it?

I want to write

````
/// # Examples
///
/// To clone something, do
///
/// ```
/// IGNORE_FOR_COMPILATION_BUT_SHOW: let cloned = myValue.clone();
/// # let cloned = 5.clone();
/// ```
````

And I want to get:

#### Examples

To clone somthing, do

```
let cloned = myValue.clone();
```

---

But the compiler should still compile the example (cloning the 5).

**EDIT**: I also want cargo to run the example, but leave out one line.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I *think* you have to add `ignore` after the first three backticks.

Comment: @Shepmaster Because there is no `myValue` (Could be fixed in this example by adding a let). What I need it for is to use an associated method of a trait on a type which I do not want to show in the documentation because it is not restricted to that one.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt no cargo just won't run it then except you use something like --all

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550665

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#attributes) says you can do this:

````
/// ```rust,ignore
/// highlighted as rust code but ignored by rustdoc
/// ```
````

There is also `rust,no_run` which compiles but doesn't run the example code.

Alternatively, you could use the same solution as you would in ordinary code: comment it out.

````
/// ```rust
/// let x=5;
/// // x = 6;  // won't be run
/// assert_eq!(x, 5);
/// ```
````

Comment: The code will still be compiled, so the test will fail

Comment: With ignore, or no_run?

Comment: with `no_run`; `ignore` isn't a perfect solution, because it is for tests which are too expensive but can be run when appropriate

Comment: How about just a comment?

Comment: The link is not correct anymore and I didn't find where it's written now.

Answer (score 6):

If  you want to ignore a part of Rust code in doctests, you might want to read the section on [running documentation tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/documentation.html#running-documentation-tests). Basically extract that code into a different block and set that block to `rust,ignore`.

This will ignore `IGNORE_FOR_COMPILATION_BUT_SHOW` completely, but the rest will run:

````
///```rust,ignore
///IGNORE_FOR_COMPILATION_BUT_SHOW: let cloned = myValue.clone(); 
///```

///```rust
/// # let cloned = 5.clone();
/// ```
````

If you want rustdoc to compile your doc tests, but not run it, you can use `rust,no_run`

Comment: Is there also a way to run it? So to run every line except the ignored one?

Comment: You can create several blocks, some ignored, some running normally. They are always displayed, they just don't run etc.